# FQL Getting comments without access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, access-token, facebook-comments

**Main question:** Is it possible to get comments using FQL without access_token?

**Description:**

At first I have added comment from my personal account:
https://api.facebook.com/method/comments.add?text=test&xid=some_xid&access_token=user_access_token&format=json

----------
*Btw. In response I got "685513" - what does this number mean?*
----------

Then I'm trying to read comments using FQL, so:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20text%20from%20comment%20where%20xid=%22same_xid_as_above%22&access_token=some_access_token

This is working ok. Result:

> {"data": [{"text": "test"}]}

But when I call same URL without access_token param it returns empty data object:

> {"data": [ ]}

I know that I can get token for my application using app id+app secret and then use it with API, but my question is if I am able to get comments **without any** access_token.

Regards,
Mateusz.

Comment: Hi, mateusz, could tell me waht is xid? how did you get it? I want to use the same api, but i always get error msg that "wrong application id"... i put commentbox on my host(a specific url), and if i run graph api with the url, i get some kinda of id number, is that the number xid? Thanks

Comment: xid is whatever you want, e.g. "my_xid_which_indentify_my_thread". It seems like your error is not not related to xid, you set wrong app id, as API say.

Answer (score 1):

- No, you can't get user data from the Graph or REST APIs without an access token. That would mean anyone could get at the comment, which would be an invasion of your privacy
- The number you get back is the ID of the comment

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/comments.add/ gives a good explanation of what permissions are needed and what the response types are

Comment: Ok, I understand. But everyone can read comments from Comments Box (even if sb is not logged in to facebook) so where's the difference if I get this comments via API or directly from Comments Box?

Comment: That's a good question. It's really a matter of user expectation. When a user posts a comment in the comment plugin on your site, it's akin to posting your comment in a forum - it's expected to be public on that forum.

When you make a Graph or REST API call to Facebook, you're requesting all the comments from the user, not just the ones in the comments plugin. The user has not agreed to share that with the world. Make sense?

Comment: BTW, you should be using the Graph API and not the REST API these days. REST is dying